# Ping pong paddle not hitting ball correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pong

I'm trying to make a Ping Pong game in Python 3 and I've gotten arguably far. I have now encountered a bug (bug not an error) that the ball doesn't bounce off when it hits the paddle edge. Instead, it waits until it has hit the center of the paddle; probably due to the ycor function that I have used. This is the code I have so far:

```
import turtle
    


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.title("Ping Pong")
wn.tracer(0)
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)


pad1 = turtle.Turtle()
pad1.shape('square')
pad1.penup()
pad1.shapesize(5, 1)
pad1.speed(0)
pad1.goto(-340, 0)
pad1.speed(0)


pad2 = turtle.Turtle()
pad2.shape('square')
pad2.penup()
pad2.shapesize(5, 1)
pad2.speed(0)
pad2.goto(340, 0)
pad2.speed(0)

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.penup()

ball.color('black')
ball.speed(0)
ball.dy = -0.2
ball.dx = -0.2


def paddle_a_up():
    y = pad1.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad1.sety(y)


def paddle_a_down():
    y = pad1.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad1.sety(y)


def paddle_b_up():
    y = pad2.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad2.sety(y)


def paddle_b_down():
    y = pad2.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad2.sety(y)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")

wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
while True:
    wn.update()
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)



    if ball.ycor() < -270:
        ball.dy *= -1


    if ball.ycor() > 280:
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -380:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1



    if ball.xcor() > 380:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1



    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < pad2.ycor() + 40 and 
ball.ycor() > pad2.ycor - 40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

It's the

```
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < pad2.ycor() + 40 and 
ball.ycor() > pad2.ycor - 40):
```

statement that is giving me all this trouble. I'm a beginner programmer but all types of answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> statement that is giving me all this trouble.

```
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < pad2.ycor() + 40 and 
ball.ycor() > pad2.ycor - 40):
```

There is no problem only a typo issue from you, you are calling a method as a property which is why you are getting this replace `pad2.ycor` to `pad2.ycor()` in above line so your line becomes

```
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < pad2.ycor() + 40 and 
ball.ycor() > pad2.ycor() - 40):
```

Also for first pad you missed the conditional pair to evaluate its collision with ball after optimizing and adding that extra condition your code now becomes following

```
import turtle
    


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.title("Ping Pong")
wn.tracer(0)
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)


pad1 = turtle.Turtle()
pad1.shape('square')
pad1.penup()
pad1.shapesize(5, 1)
pad1.speed(0)
pad1.goto(-340, 0)
pad1.speed(0)


pad2 = turtle.Turtle()
pad2.shape('square')
pad2.penup()
pad2.shapesize(5, 1)
pad2.speed(0)
pad2.goto(340, 0)
pad2.speed(0)

ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.shape("circle")
ball.penup()

ball.color('black')
ball.speed(0)
ball.dy = -0.2
ball.dx = -0.2


def paddle_a_up():
    y = pad1.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad1.sety(y)


def paddle_a_down():
    y = pad1.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad1.sety(y)


def paddle_b_up():
    y = pad2.ycor()
    y += 20
    pad2.sety(y)


def paddle_b_down():
    y = pad2.ycor()
    y -= 20
    pad2.sety(y)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")

wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")
while True:
    wn.update()
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)

    if ball.ycor() < -270 or ball.ycor() > 280:
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -380 or ball.xcor() > 380:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
    
    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < pad1.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > pad1.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < pad2.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > pad2.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: I fixed that but it still doesn't work

Comment: i executed your code after fixing this and now the collision is good working from edges and center two i mean the any part of pad .

Comment: your python version?

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: my side both paddles are working i can play the game lolz .